# Saving without dialog window

Tags: javascript, photoshop

I'm trying to write a script that will automate a bunch of stuff for Photoshop CS5. Part of this involves saving a bunch of files. Is there a way to save a file in a way that doesn't open up a dialog window? I've been looking over the [JavaScript Tools Guide](http://wwwimages.adobe.com/www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/products/indesign/pdfs/JavaScriptToolsGuide_CS5.pdf), but I didn't see a way to do this. [This](http://macscripter.net/viewtopic.php?id=15520) suggested I used an action to deal with it but I'd really prefer not to do that.

**EDIT:** specifically I want to save the files as crytiff format but I'd just like to know how to save a file with whatever extension I want

Comment: A "Save As" kind of window

Comment: Save and Close option doesn't work for you?

Comment: Sorry, I do not know what you are talking about. Save and Close method? Clicking Save and Close? What?

Answer (score 1):

The following saves the active document as PNG. You can change the type to save it as.

```
// reference open doc
var doc = app.activeDocument;

// set save options
var opts = new ExportOptionsSaveForWeb();

opts.PNG8 = false;
opts.transparency = true;
opts.interlaced = false;
opts.quality = 100;
opts.includeProfile = false;
opts.format = SaveDocumentType.PNG; // Document Type

// save png file in same folder as open doc
activeDocument.exportDocument(doc.path, ExportType.SAVEFORWEB, opts);
```

Comment: sorry I didn't specify, I don't want to save as PNG

Comment: all you need to do is replace the PNG in `opts.format = SaveDocumentType.PNG;` to the format you want.

Comment: does using the Save for Web option cause any difficulties if I don't plan on using it for the web?

Comment: That object provides Save for web options. You could use `TiffSaveOptions` and specify the parameters you want to use.

(i.e
`params = new TiffSaveOptions();
params.byteOrder = ByteOrder.MACOS;
params.layers = false;
params.transparency = true;
params.alphaChannels = true;
params.embedColorProfile = false;
params.imageCompression = TIFFEncoding.TIFFLZW;
params.saveImagePyramid = false;` )

[Ref](http://www.pmview.com/help/pmview/tiff_save_options.html)

Answer (score 0):

Try using `Document.saveAs()`. But, like El Cas said, you still have to pass in some kind of SaveOptions object. You don't necessarily have to specify all the options if you don't want. You can just use the generic object like this:

```
app.activeDocument.saveAs(new File(doc.path + "/myDocument"), TiffSaveOptions);
// or BMPSaveOptions or GIFSaveOptions or JPEGSaveOptions...
```

Here's a much more complete [Photoshop CS5 Javascript Reference](http://wwwimages.adobe.com/www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/photoshop/pdfs/photoshop_cs5_javascript_ref.pdf)

Answer (score 0):

Open:
Windows > Actions 
You will find Toggle Dialog On/Off check box before every action. Turn it off.