# Overwrite/save image as PNG without the 'Save as..' dialog

Tags: javascript, photoshop, photoshop-script

I have a master document that is saved in a location. This master document has one big sprite. On running my script, multiple new documents are created with the sprite in various patterns. I'd like to save these multiple new documents as PNGs without needing to access the "Save As..." dialogs and close them.

```
    // ==============================================================
    // This code is run on the master document to get the Path.
    // The saved directory location of the main master document.
    Path = doc.path;  // If the document is new there is no doc.path. Error is shown.
    // ==============================================================

    // ==============================================================
    // This code is run at the end of the multiple new documents that's created.
    // Save the file.
    var Name = doc.name.replace(/\.[^\.]+$/, '');
    var Suffix = "";
    var saveFile = File(Path + "/" + Name + Suffix + ".png");
    if (saveFile.exists) saveFile.remove();
    var pngOptions = new PNGSaveOptions();
    pngOptions.compression = 0;
    pngOptions.interlaced = false;
    activeDocument.saveAs(saveFile, pngOptions, false, Extension.LOWERCASE);
    doc.close(SaveOptions.DONOTSAVECHANGES);
    // ==============================================================
```

Comment: possible duplicate --> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14389175/saving-without-dialog-window

Comment: How did I miss that?? It works! But how do I save 2 copies of a document with different save file names? It doesn't have a save file name argument. Or should I ask in that thread?

Comment: it has, `doc.path`. Simply replace it with your `saveFile`. If no file name is specified, PS uses an active document file name.

Comment: @SergeyKritskiy I'll try that out when I'm on my home pc. But I have a serious question which I can't seem to add it within the conversation of the other thread because I don't have 50 reputations. So I followed the codes provided in the other thread and it works fine on my Windows PC. But I passed the script file to my partner, he uses a Mac, it doesn't work. This is the error he showed me: https://imgur.com/a/8gLh6Au . Do you by any chance know why this might happen?

Comment: Simply ask a new question: with the reference to that post, code and the path that doesn't work for you.

Answer (score 4):

Even though you found a solution, I'd like also to answer your original question: how to suppress a dialog — this is sometimes useful. You can do that by changing a Photoshop `app.displayDialogs` property:

```
app.displayDialogs = DialogModes.NO; // no dialogs will be displayed

// your code

app.displayDialogs = DialogModes.ERROR; // default value
```

It can be also `DialogModes.ALL` in cases you explicitly want to show UI.

Comment: Is this a toggle type function? Meaning if I left it as "app.displayDialogs = DialogModes.NO;" no UI will popup until I restart my Photoshop again, right?

Comment: Actually I think it's until you'll set this option again