# Auto-saving works on Windows but not on a Mac

Tags: javascript, photoshop, photoshop-script

I followed the code provided in this thread ([Saving without dialog window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14389175/saving-without-dialog-window)) to overwrite/save image as PNG without the 'Save as..' dialog. It works fine on my Windows PC. But I passed the script file to my partner, he uses a Mac, it doesn't work. This is the error he showed me:

[image: error]

Here is the script:

```
    // The saved directory location of the main master document.
    Path = doc.path;  // If the document is new there is no doc.path. Error is shown.

    // Save the file.
    var opts = new ExportOptionsSaveForWeb();
    opts.PNG8 = false;
    opts.transparency = true;
    opts.interlaced = false;
    opts.quality = 100;
    opts.includeProfile = false;
    opts.format = SaveDocumentType.PNG;
    activeDocument.exportDocument(Path, ExportType.SAVEFORWEB, opts);
    doc.close(SaveOptions.DONOTSAVECHANGES);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Photoshop it's usually difficult to say why a hacky thing works on one OS but doesn't on the other, I'd suggest just to give a full path name to `.exportDocument()`:

```
activeDocument.exportDocument(new File(Path + "/" + doc.name.replace(/\.[^.]+$/g, ".png")), ExportType.SAVEFORWEB, opts);
```

Comment: I tried it out on my Windows PC to make sure it works fine before sending it over to my partner. For some weird reason, it saves but without its '.png' extension (but the data is there). I right-clicked the saved file > went into properties > added '.png' at the back of its file's name > hit apply and it changes to a proper png file. Not sure why this happens because your code already has '.png'.

Comment: mine replaces active document extension with png. I guess if your active document doesn't have an extension to replace it doesn't add the png... maybe do `doc.name.replace(/\.[^.]+$/g, "") + ".png"`?

Comment: Ahh yes, I forgot to mention it doesn't have an extension because it's a tempory duplicated doc of the master document. So I have the path of the master doc's saved location. Anyway, that code works on my Windows! Now I'll wait for my partner to get back to me :)